# Where is OpenCV's C++ noArray() in the Source Code?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, wrapper

Just a quick question..I grepped through the source and found so many hits, it was impossible to look through.  Tried saving the output of grep to a file i.e.

```
grep -r "noArray" . >> search
```

and then searching through the "search "file for typedef and enum...but nothing came up,,,I would just like to find it so I can wrap it in C.  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

With OpenCV 2.4.8, the function is declared in `modules\core\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp:1453`:

```
CV_EXPORTS OutputArray noArray();
```

And it is defined in `modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:1731`:

```
static _OutputArray _none;
OutputArray noArray() { return _none; }
```

**EDIT**

`_none` is a static object of type `_OutputArray` initialized using the default constructor, which is empty (see `modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:1332`). Hence, as `_OutputArray` derives from `_InputArray`, the default constructor of `_InputArray` is also called. This second constructor is defined in `modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:921` as follows:

```
_InputArray::_InputArray() : flags(0), obj(0) {}
```

where `flags` and `obj` are member variables of respective types `int` and `void*`. Hence `_none` *is not* a NULL pointer but it *contains* one.

Comment: what does the return value _none signify,  do you know? Is it a null pointer?

Comment: @user3411335 `_none` is not a NULL pointer but it contains one. See my edit.